# Upserting with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema that is defined like

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        ipAddress: String,
        pollIDs: [{
            id: String
        }]
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

What I want to create is a route that checks the requests ip address, see if it exists in the database, if it doesn't **create a new document with the ipAddress** property set accordingly and the **current req.body.poll_id** to be an element in the pollIDs array.

However, if there is a document with that ip address I want the req.body.poll_id to be **pushed** into the pollIDs array.

I would demonstrate my first attempt, but I know that I've messed up the parameters on the findOneAndUpdate call.

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {'user.ipAddress': req.body.ipAddress},
    {$push: {'user.pollIDs': {id: req.body.poll_id}}},
    {upsert: true, new: true},
    (err, doc) => {...});
```

The upsert will take the query object and apply the update operation to it in the case where it needs to insert a new document.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out!

Comment: So I tried the solution, but I keep coming up with an error about the push being empty

Comment: @daman There is no `returnOriginal` options, the answer is wrong. Please use `new: true` instead of `returnOriginal: false` and you will get  back the updated document.

Comment: @Festo Right, `returnOriginal` is for the native driver, Mongoose uses `new`. Updated.

Comment: @daman The `$push` field was missing the `user.` prefix. Try it now.